# javascript date format strings

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a date being returned in a json result that looks like this...

```
2014-11-24T16:59:59
```

In my jqgrid I need to specify the input date string for this date and also the output format i.e. how it will look like on the grid.

```
    formatoptions: {
        srcformat: 'Y-m-d',
        newformat: 'd/m/y hh:mi:ss'
    },
```

I would like the grid to have an output date format with the "T" removed and the time date and portion displayed like this.

```
2014-11-22 16:59:59
```

Can someone help me with how I should specify this in the format options. i.e. How the date strings should looke like. I've been looking around with no success.

thanks

Comment: That is a defined date format (ISO 8601 : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601 ) that, according to the docs for jqgrid, can be indicated with `SortableDateTime`, so : `scrformat: SortableDateTime`. no need to deal with removing the `T`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use like this :

```
formatter: 'date',
formatoptions: {
            srcformat: 'ISO8601Long',
            newformat: 'd/m/Y H:i:s'
}
```

[Jsfiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/n51qog2x/)